# How to get / make a "Read-Only" storage

Tags: storage, usb-storage, read-only

So I've been trying to make a custom efi firmware( .efi file ) and store them in a FAT32 storage device for my own computer to make my computer look like that I've made. What I'm trying to deal is that I'm worried that my FAT32 storage is read and writable and I don't want that. I've searched for things like making a USB flash drive read only which I don't know how to do, making the storage device read only with **diskpart** which can be tinkered again to remove read only protection and using a CD-R or DVD-R as CDFS to store the efi firmware which is not useful as a rom. Is there any small most importantly **read only storage device**  out there that I can use?

Answer (score 1):

After a quick search, I found [this informative write-up](https://www.getusb.info/how-to-make-a-usb-read-only/) which outlines the diskpart method and its limitations, as you mentioned.  It also linked to [a Nexcopy product page](https://www.nexcopy.com/usb-secure-flash-drives/), but unfortunately the "Buy Now" link is `mailto:contact@nexcopy.com`, so that may not be what you're looking for in terms of time frame.

Sadly, for something like hardware level write protection on disposable USB flash drives, I think the market is just not really large enough for an easy to use (ie. no soldering required) solution to have found wide adoption.

Comment: Is there a specific circuit to disable "Write permission"

Comment: @Mhi2002 I don't believe there is, but theoretically you could write to the flash memory of a drive, then desolder the write enabled USB controller, and replace it with one that is read only.  I honestly don't know how feasible this is, but if you're handy with a soldering iron and have access to some old read only flash drives, it might be worth opening the casing and inspecting the chips on the boards, there are definitely worse ways of destroying flash drives, lol